# Theme Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, ingress-game

I recently managed to get an Ingress invite, and love the way the maps are themed in that.

I know similar theming can be done for Google Maps in a browser, [as shown here](http://codecanyon.net/item/5-color-themes-for-google-maps-api/2500863).

Does anybody know how Ingress themed the map on Android? Is this a feature only available to Google, or can we use it in our apps through the standard maps library?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that it is not available yet, but that at some point it will be available upon popular request. Do you like the game? Waiting for invite.

Comment: I saw similar theming in another Google app, don't recall which, but it was quite a bit back.

Comment: The game is decent. Haven't had much time to play it. Got the invite just today morning.

Comment: @Raghav Sood did you find the answer on your question? Wanting to do something simular

Comment: @StephanCelis Afraid not. It seems like the themeing is Google's own inhouse project for now.

Comment: @RaghavSood is this maybe possible to do now or not yet?

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic I still haven't been able to find any way to do this via any SDK on Android.

Comment: oki thanks, hope they will make something I really need this asap.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is a guess (a lot more of a guess for me than usual)

The MapView itself is a view. There's constructors to take in contexts and attributes. You might be able to play with a ContextThemeWrapper or extend the mapview and do things with onDraw().

Answer (score 1):

As of September 21, 2016, Google has released a feature to allow you to theme maps in a very flexible way, using JSON files that provide the theme with color for the various elements. They have also released a small web app to allow you to experiment with themes, which they have released at: [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

You can also find Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) on this feature.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Google Map has themes. But We have one way of getting the themed map for android app is MapBoxSDK.

https://www.mapbox.com

mapbox sdk is similar like google map regarding the function name and other stuff. Only change is you have to use mapboxview instead of mapView in android.

This one gives you customized map skin.